# After editing Parent, update an association with parent columns attributes? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't get my subscription to update with my product and also duplicate the attributes of the product to the same fields as my subscription table.

My associations are, `subscriptions` and `products` belong to a `User` but a `Product` has many `subscriptions`.

**Subscription.rb**

```
class Subscription
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => :subscriber_id, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Then the `Product` and `Subscription` table with the same columns that I'm trying to duplicate:

```
create_table :products do |t|
   t.string  :name
   t.decimal :price
   t.integer :user_id
end

create_table :subscriptions do |t|
   t.string  :name
   t.decimal :price
   t.integer :subscriber_id # same as user_id
   t.integer :subscribable_id
   t.string  :subscribable_type
end
```

**ProductsController**

```
def edit
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
   if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
      redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Successfully Updated.')   
   else 
      render :back
   end
end
```

**ProductObserver**

```
class ProductObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_update(product)
    if self.subscriptions.find_by_subscribable_id_and_subscribable_type(subscribable_id, subscribable_type)
        subscription = Subscription.find_by_subscribable_id_and_subscribable_type(subscribable_id, subscribable_type)
        self.subscription.update_attributes(params[:subscription]).select{ |key, _| Subscription.attribute_names.include? key })
    end
  end
end
```

What the `after_update` is suppose to do is:

1. Check if a subscription for the particular product exist and if it does....
2. Update the current users subscription with the products new edited attributes.

Right now, the Subscription doesn't update when the Product does. What do I need to fix about this code to get it to do this? What about when duplicating the product fields to its subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that was just a typo, but your observer is wrong. `self` is not your product in an observer. Instead you should use `product` (the given parameter)  instead.

Secondly your lookup of the subscriptions seems wrong too. You are using `subscribable_id` and `subscribable_type` which are not defined and thus just `nil`. I think you want to use `product.id` and `'Product'`, but then you could just iterate over all subscriptions of the product. `product.subscriptions` returns all `subscriptions` linked to that product.

Lastly, if you are going to keep `price` and `name` of a subscription always in sync with the linked product, why do not something like this instead:

```
 create_table :products do |t|
   t.string  :name
   t.decimal :price
   t.integer :user_id
end

create_table :subscriptions do |t|
   t.integer :subscriber_id # same as user_id
   t.integer :subscribable_id
   t.string  :subscribable_type
end
```

and inside your subscription model do

```
class Subscription
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true

  delegate :name, :price, :to => :subscribable, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in `:autosave => true` into your associations options.

You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Nothing happened when I put that in my `Product` model; `has_many subscriptions, :autosave => true`